# Emacs `shell` and `eshell` on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, console, ag

I have some of the console commands I would like to use from Emacs, namely `ag`. It works great in `CMD` or *Far Manager*. However when I use it from Emacs `shell` or `eshell` I run into a problem which may be (slight chance, though) `ag`-specific.

When I run `shell` and then run `ag` it returns result (help screen) immediately. If I run it searching for a line in files inside directory as `ag needle`, it hangs and doesn't return anything.

If I run it as `ag needle .` it returns result immediately, however missing file names and  lines numbers, `--color` and `-nogroup` options do not affect the printed result in this case.

When I run it via `shell-command` it returns the correct result (with file names and line numbers). `eshell` has the  same problem.

What do I need to do to make these commands work in `shell` and/or `eshell` ?

It's been noted in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380470/emacs-shell-and-eshell-input-output) that Win32 has issues with subprocess buffering. Is there a way to fix it?